# Find a $\mathcal{L}$-formula to fullfill a condition

Tags: logic, model-theory

> Let $\mathcal{L} = \{f,g\}$ where $f$ is binary and $g$ unary. Consider the $\mathcal{L}$-structure $\mathfrak{M}$ with underlying set $\mathbb{R}$ and $f^{\mathfrak{M}}$ is the default multiplication, $g^{\mathfrak{M}}$ is the sine function.
>
> Give an $\mathcal{L}$-formula $\phi(x)$ with one free variable $x$ such that $\forall a\in \mathbb{R}$:
> $$\mathfrak{M} \vDash \phi(a) \Leftrightarrow \text{there is an $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a=(2n+0.5)\pi$}$$

I guess the missing constant symbols create a problem here?
I was thinking of using something like to avoid the $1$-symbol, but now I'm using the $0$-symbol... How can I solve this problem?

$$\phi(x) = \exists y(y\not = 0 \wedge f(y,y)=y \wedge g(x) = y)$$

Comment: You can define $1$ as the unique $y$ so that $\forall x f(x,y)=x$

Comment: Alternatively, $y\ne 0$ can be expressed as $\exists x: x\cdot y\ne y$.